# boxplot not show the plots

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Following this [tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-step-by-step-introduction-to-pca-c0d78e26a0dd), I used the first few statements in order to show the distribution of iris data as below

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np
iris = load_iris()
colors = ["blue", "red", "green"]
df = DataFrame(
    data=np.c_[iris["data"], iris["target"]], columns=iris["feature_names"] + ["target"]
)
print (df)
df.boxplot(by="target", layout=(2, 2), figsize=(10, 10))
```

Problem is that I don't see the boxplot output although the `df` is not empty.

```
$ python3 pca_iris.py
     sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  petal length (cm)  petal width (cm)  target
0                  5.1               3.5                1.4               0.2     0.0
1                  4.9               3.0                1.4               0.2     0.0
2                  4.7               3.2                1.3               0.2     0.0
3                  4.6               3.1                1.5               0.2     0.0
4                  5.0               3.6                1.4               0.2     0.0
..                 ...               ...                ...               ...     ...
145                6.7               3.0                5.2               2.3     2.0
146                6.3               2.5                5.0               1.9     2.0
147                6.5               3.0                5.2               2.0     2.0
148                6.2               3.4                5.4               2.3     2.0
149                5.9               3.0                5.1               1.8     2.0

[150 rows x 5 columns]
$
```

How can I debug more to see what is the problem with boxplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using jupyter notebook and the same code showed me the plots. if you are use python code I think you have to use

```
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

to see the plots